# RTCFATAL Exception error is instantly crashing my react native app in Testflight

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, testflight, apple-developer

I currently have an application that I created. I am done with the development part and now I want to deploy my app to the Apple App Store for review. Right now, I am building it and testing it on Testflight. It runs perfectly in my local environment, but on test flight the app almost instantly crashes. I looked at the crash logs and couldnt understand why it is crashing from the logs. Can anyone help me figure out what is causing the crash for my app??

I am building it with `eas build -p ios` and then download the `.ipa` file after the build is complete. I then upload the `.ipa` file into transporter and submit my app to my apple developer account. Then i send it out for testing through Testflight.

Here is the crash reports:

[image: crash report1]

[image: crash report2]

Answer (score 0):

Check the error message and review Xcode logs for more information.
Ensure you have generated and uploaded debug symbols (dSYM file) for accurate crash reporting.
Analyze memory usage using Xcode's Instruments tool to identify memory-related issues.
Update third-party libraries and dependencies to the latest versions.
Test the app on different iOS devices to determine if the crash is device-specific.
Consider integrating error monitoring tools like Crashlytics or Sentry.
Seek help from the React Native community if the issue persists.